# Логично ли составлено предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, лексика

*В адрес службы поступил звонок.*

Comment: https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj8KHdCw0LTRgNC10YEg0L%2FQvtGB0YLRg9C%2F0LjQu9C%2BKhcKCAgAEAoYMiAKIAAohOaWzt3b%2BA1ABTICCAE6AQEwAQ%3D%3D

Answer (score 0):

Поступить звонок в адрес вряд ли может. Предложение стоит перестроить.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы звонят в саму службу, а не в её адрес)) (А пишут и делают замечания, если что — ПО адресу.)